# WildFly deploy failed : missing jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.PostgreSql

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am new in Jboss/Wildfly.
I created simple EAR application in Eclipse using Maven archetype:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly.archetype/wildfly-javaee7-webapp-ear-blank-archetype/8.2.0.Final

My standalone.xml -http://wklej.to/fhzg8
I am using WildFly 8.2

I have two files:
 + Przychodnia-ds.xml
 + presistence.xml

**Przychodnia-ds.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This is an unmanaged datasource. It should be used for proofs of concept 
   or testing only. It uses H2, an in memory database that ships with JBoss 
   AS. -->
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
   <!-- The datasource is bound into JNDI at this location. We reference 
      this in META-INF/persistence.xml 
    <datasource jndi-name="java:/PostgreSql/Przychodnia" pool-name="Przychodnia"
        enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Przychodnia;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
        <driver>postgres</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>postgres</user-name>
            <password>postgres</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    -->

</datasources>
```

**Second file (persistence.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed 
         data source, this example data source is just for development and testing! -->
      <!-- The datasource is deployed as <EAR>/META-INF/Przychodnia-ds.xml, you
         can find it in the source at ear/src/main/application/META-INF/Przychodnia-ds.xml -->
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/PostgreSql/Przychodnia</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
20:47:33,988 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
20:47:34,305 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
20:47:34,387 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" starting
20:47:36,232 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment Przychodnia-ear.ear
20:47:36,247 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found Przychodnia-ear.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Przychodnia-ear.ear.dodeploy
20:47:36,291 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
20:47:36,331 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO version 3.3.0.Final
20:47:36,347 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-5) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.0.Final
20:47:36,461 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.6.Final
20:47:36,497 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
20:47:36,504 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
20:47:36,518 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.4)
20:47:36,522 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
20:47:36,525 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.9.Final)
20:47:36,543 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
20:47:36,553 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = postgres
20:47:36,554 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
20:47:36,588 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
20:47:36,621 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS010153: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
20:47:36,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
20:47:36,659 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.21.Final
20:47:36,677 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
20:47:36,734 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.1.0.Final starting
20:47:36,759 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.1.0.Final starting
20:47:36,776 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
20:47:36,786 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
20:47:37,057 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path /opt/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/welcome-content
20:47:37,073 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
20:47:37,136 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
20:47:37,391 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /0.0.0.0:28080
20:47:37,930 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/PostgreSql/Przychodnia]
20:47:37,930 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
20:47:38,021 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /opt/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments
20:47:38,051 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "Przychodnia-ear.ear" (runtime-name: "Przychodnia-ear.ear")
20:47:38,323 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015973: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "Przychodnia-ejb.jar")
20:47:38,325 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015973: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "Przychodnia-web.war")
20:47:38,632 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.3.2.Final
20:47:38,766 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for primary
20:47:38,908 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'Przychodnia-ear.ear/Przychodnia-ejb.jar#primary'
20:47:38,917 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment Przychodnia-ear.ear
20:47:38,940 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: primary
    ...]
20:47:39,053 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
20:47:39,086 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.7.Final}
20:47:39,099 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
20:47:39,104 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
20:47:39,264 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment Przychodnia-ejb.jar
20:47:39,325 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment Przychodnia-web.war
20:47:39,405 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: Przychodnia-ear.ear
20:47:39,474 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) WELD-000900: 2.2.6 (Final)
20:47:39,511 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment Przychodnia-ear.ear
20:47:39,950 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'Przychodnia-ear.ear/Przychodnia-ejb.jar#primary'
20:47:40,092 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
20:47:40,905 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
20:47:40,929 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
20:47:41,112 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
20:47:41,721 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
20:47:41,721 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
20:47:41,738 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000396: Updating schema
20:47:41,803 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000261: Table found: public.osoba
20:47:41,803 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000037: Columns: [surname, name, id]
20:47:41,804 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
20:47:41,804 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000126: Indexes: [osoba_pkey]
20:47:41,807 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) HHH000232: Schema update complete
20:47:41,883 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Przychodnia-ear.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.Przychodnia-ear.Przychodnia-web.DefaultDataSource is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.PostgreSql]"]}
20:47:41,964 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "Przychodnia-ear.ear" (runtime-name : "Przychodnia-ear.ear")
20:47:41,967 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.PostgreSql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Przychodnia-ear.Przychodnia-web.DefaultDataSource] 

20:47:42,072 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
20:47:42,073 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
20:47:42,073 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started (with errors) in 8503ms - Started 323 of 414 services (24 services failed or missing dependencies, 108 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
20:47:42,213 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'Przychodnia-ear.ear/Przychodnia-ejb.jar#primary'
20:47:42,223 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment Przychodnia-ear.ear
20:47:42,286 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS011410: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'Przychodnia-ear.ear/Przychodnia-ejb.jar#primary'
20:47:42,303 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: Przychodnia-ejb.jar) in 98ms
20:47:42,306 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: Przychodnia-web.war) in 101ms
20:47:42,308 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Przychodnia-ear.ear (runtime-name: Przychodnia-ear.ear) in 104ms
20:47:42,423 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "Przychodnia-ear.ear" (runtime-name: "Przychodnia-ear.ear")
20:47:42,429 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Przychodnia-ear.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-ejb.jar".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Przychodnia-ear.ear".WeldStartService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."servlets.HomePage".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."servlets.HomePage".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."servlets.HomePage".JndiBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."servlets.HomePage".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web.UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."servlets.HomePage".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."servlets.HomePage".START] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".deploymentCompleteService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Przychodnia-ear.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener".START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldTerminalListener".START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.PermittedTaglibsTLV".START, JBAS014799: ... and 5 more ] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."Przychodnia-ear.ear".WeldStartService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Przychodnia-ear.ear".CdiValidatorFactoryService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."Przychodnia-ear.ear".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Przychodnia-ear.ear".WeldStartService] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Przychodnia-ear.Przychodnia-web.BeanManager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Przychodnia-ear.Przychodnia-web.DefaultContextService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Przychodnia-ear.Przychodnia-web.DefaultDataSource (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Przychodnia-ear.Przychodnia-web.DefaultManagedExecutorService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Przychodnia-ear.Przychodnia-web.DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Przychodnia-ear.Przychodnia-web.DefaultManagedThreadFactory (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Przychodnia-ear.Przychodnia-web.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Przychodnia-ear.Przychodnia-web.UserTransaction (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.Przychodnia-ear.Przychodnia-web.env (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".jndiDependencyService] 
      service jboss.persistenceunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear/Przychodnia-ejb.jar#primary" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."Przychodnia-ear.ear".WeldStartService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."Przychodnia-ear.ear"."Przychodnia-web.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web.UndertowDeploymentInfoService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web.codec (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Przychodnia-web.UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 

20:47:46,993 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found Przychodnia-ear.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called Przychodnia-ear.ear.dodeploy
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Show logs.  Deploy failed. How Can I resolve my problem ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must download JDBC driver for PostgreSQL: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Then configure it like this article: http://dmitrypukhov.pro/configure-jboss-and-postgresql-jdbc-datasource/

Answer (score 1):

Dear Friend from another site ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°), where you linked to this topic.

Please note the row where the first error appears:

```
 20:05:33,363 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Przychodnia-ear.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.Przychodnia-ear.Przychodnia-web.DefaultDataSource is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.PostgreSql]"]}
```

The very end of this row says: *"DefaultDataSource is missing"* so probably you didn't deploy DataSource along with your app (or perhaphs the DataSource itself couldn't be deployed - in case of problem with deployment of you database connector .jar) or your application expects DataSource with different name than the deployed one. Please check if your datasource and database connector are properly deployed, and then names of data source.

Comment: http://x3.cdn03.imgwykop.pl/c3201142/comment_PfEVrVCfkx5JlJkRCHl5infvChI6Ev9K.jpg

Comment: Hahhaahh ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°),

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved.
The error was in standalone.xml file.

```
<default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSql" jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
```

My datasource is java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSql/**Przychodnia**

No comment.